# Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' at line 12 column 7

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class listexample {

    public list<string> myval {get;set;}
    public string str;
          public listexample(){
            myval=new list<string>();
            myval.add('India');
            myval.add('USA');
            myval.add('Japan');
            myval.add(1,'China');
                    }
   str =  myval.get(2);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str =  myval.get(2);
```

Should be inside constructor

```
public class listexample {

    public list<string> myval {get;set;}
    public string str    {get; private set;}

    public listexample(){
            myval=new list<string>();
            myval.add('India');
            myval.add('USA');
            myval.add('Japan');
            myval.add(1,'China');
            str =  myval.get(2);
     }
}
```

Also since you are using `str` in VF page, should be in get set property

```
 public string str {get;set;}
```

If you are just displaying `str` in VF page. Use `private set;` to ensure this String should not updated from vf page.

Comment: Thank you Ratan for the detailed response..thanks very much.